# Check for separator after every 2 characters

Tags: python

Is there a way to check if there is a separator after every 2 characters in a string.

For example:

```
x = '32-21-44-33':
  # if there is '-' after every 2 digits, return True

# so if x = '231-21-21-21' it would return as False
```

Comment: What should the output be if `x='32-21-44-33-'`?

Answer (score 3):

I would phrase your requirement using the regex pattern:

```regex
^\d{2}(?:-\d{2})*$
```

Sample script:

```py
inp = '32-21-44-33'
if re.search(r'^\d{2}(?:-\d{2})*$', inp):
    print("MATCH")   # prints MATCH
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to slice string and check using `all()`.

If you just want **to check that `-` is at every 3 position** in your string, then you can simply do:

```
>>> my_str = '32-21-44-33'
>>> all(x=='-' for x in my_str[2::3])
True
```

And if you **want to ensure that "-" is present at only at third position and not any where else**, then you can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) as:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby

>>> all(list(j)[0] == '-' if i else len(list(j))==2 for i, j in groupby(my_str, key=lambda x: x=='-'))
True
```

However, if you want **to ensure that your string is strictly following the pattern of two numbers followed by "-"**, then you can achieve that by additionally using `zip()` with sliced strings as:

```
>>> all(z=='-' and (x + y).isdigit() for x, y, z in zip(my_str[::3], my_str[1::3], my_str[2::3]))
True
```

Comment: This returns true for invalid strings such as `'32-21-44-33--'`, `'32-21-44-33-1'`, `'32-21-44----33'` etc.

Comment: @mhawke thanks for pointing it, i have corrected it now

Answer (score 2):

the best and easiest way is

```
z = x.split("-")
for j in z:
    if len(j)!=2 :
        print("false")
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. It is full of syntax errors and this doesn't work.

Comment: they can manage syntaxes I am new to stackoverflow so I don't know how to properly indent a code

Comment: No, it's not just about the indent. This answer is just wrong.

Comment: I think this is ok now

Comment: You should check for all the cases when you write an answer.

Comment: Its not entirely wrong. Its just that you need to modify the if statement `if len(j)!=2: return False`.

Comment: Because your code will pass the following case `x = '3-21-4-33'`. As when you split all the strings in the list have length less than 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` with `-` as a delimiter to break up the words, then use `all()` to ensure that all have the desired length or other properties:

```
>>> x = '32-21-44-33'
>>> all(len(s) == 2 for s in x.split('-'))
True
>>> x = '231-21-21-21'
>>> all(len(s) == 2 for s in x.split('-'))
False
```

If you want to ensure that they are all numeric too:

```
>>> x = '32-21-44-33'
>>> all(len(s) == 2 and s.isdigit() for s in x.split('-'))
True
>>> x = '32-ab-44-33'
>>> all(len(s) == 2 and s.isdigit() for s in x.split('-'))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Check every 3rd character to see if it is equal to a dash.  If it isn't, immediately return false.  If you reach the end of the string, return true.

```
x = 2
while x < len(mystring):
    if mystring[x] != '-':
        return False
    x += 3
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the delimiter there's a easy "comprehensible" way to do it

```
x = '32-21-45-33'
    
# split list with the third char of the string, then sort the list by element length

sorted_list = sorted(x.split(x[2]), key=len)

# if your first element length is equal to your last element length all element are the same length

if len(sorted_list[0]) == len(sorted_list[len(sorted_list) - 1]):
   print("ok")
else
    print("nok")
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here you get a oneliner returning the bolean + the unknown delimiter**

```
def check_every_n(x,n):
    return (len(list(set([x[i] for i in range(n,len(x)-n) if (i+1) % (n+1) == 0]))) == 1), x[n]

x = '32-21-44-33'

n = 2

print (check_every_n(x,n))
```

You take your string `x`, your test `n`, you use list comprehension to build a list of elements every `n` in the string, you remove duplicates, if `len() = 1` means there is the same element every `n`, and so you return the bolean check + the delimiter at position `n` index `n - 1`.

Output:

```
(True, '-') # n = 2
(False, '2') # n = 3
```

Worthless to say, if the boolean is False, the delimiter is meaningless.

With this you can check for any kind of delimiter every n. So you don't need to mention it. Plus you can loop to find any delimiter at any n if you like.

Let say, return bolean and delimiter, if any, with spacing from 2 to `len(x)//3` (to allow repeats):

```
x = '2403-0132-1321-3123'

for n in range(2,len(x)//3):

    print (n,check_every_n(x,n))
```

Output:

```
2 (False, '0')
3 (True, '3')
4 (True, '-')
5 (False, '0')
```